# How to change the textview height if it contains more than 10 words in Kotlin (Code)

Tags: android, kotlin, if-statement, textview, size

it's a very simple question but I can't find a good solution (in Kotlin) for this problem.

**The textview height should change if the textview contains more than 10 words.**

*Change size from 10dp to 20dp.*

Thanks in advance

Comment: What part are you stuck on? This is so rudimentary, it's hard to know what you're asking for. Like, "if it contains more than 10 words" just means, use an if statement. TextView has a `setTextSize` function with documentation.

Comment: Thanks for help 
Well:

if (tv_task_name.length() >= 10){
                   
      tv_task_name.height = 10dp..... ?
     }

Comment: *Sorry 20dp not 10dp

Comment: Are you just asking how to set the height of a view?

Comment: No I need a if function which could change the height of the textview. For example: If my textview1 contains more than 10 letters --> than the height of the textview should change from 10dp to 20dp. I hope you're understanding now my problem?

Comment: If you want to know how to change the height of a TextView, the 10 words or 10 letters thing is irrelevant to your question. I'm not following why you keep mentioning that. You have two separate tasks: (1) counting the words or letters in the text and (2) setting the height of the view. Are you struggling with both of these? If so, this should be two separate questions, although the counting of words is almost certainly already answered on StackOverflow if you search.

Comment: Alright thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_task_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and 
    typesetting industry."
    android:textSize="10sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Kotlin:

```
    val tv_task_name: TextView = findViewById(R.id.tv_task_name)
    val s: CharSequence = tv_task_name.text
    val words = s.toString().trim()
    val numberOfInputWords = words.split("\\s+".toRegex()).size
    if (numberOfInputWords > 10) {
        tv_task_name.textSize = 20.0F
    }
```

Comment: Thank you but I actually need to change the layout_height to 20dp and not the textSize. Do you have another solution?

Comment: Oh I see! Then no need of above code just,
        if(tv_task_name.length() >10){
            tv_task_name.height = 20
        }---> if number letters in textview is more than 10letters

Comment: Thank you I tried this but it actually didn't work. I think the problem is that "tv_task_name.height = 20" didn't talk with the layout_height in the xml file. Do you know another solution?

Comment: If you’re trying to put a conditional in your xml, that’s not possible. You have to handle it on the Kotlin side.